# Use Powershell to create a OneDrive Shortcut for a Sharepoint folder?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

Viewing a Sharepoint folder, there is a button for "Add Shortcut to OneDrive". Clicking that creates a OneDrive Shortcut, indicated by a folder icon with a blue link decoration on it, in OneDrive MyFiles. Selecting the OneDrive Shortcut and 'Copy Link', you can see the underlying web link for the Sharepoint folder.

If I have a web link for a Sharepoint folder, is there a way to programmatically create a OneDrive Shortcut from the link?

Here's the code I have so far. It works up the the final `Add-PnPFile`, which throws the error; `Add-PnPFile : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`  I've searched for a parameter set example using these parameters and can find none.  I would think the `-ShortcutURL` would be a good search term, but no.

Any ideas what to try next?

```
# Install the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -WarningAction Ignore

# Import the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

# Define the SharePoint Online domain
$domain = "my-company-domain"

# Define the SharePoint Online URL
$spSiteName = "my-sharepoint-site"
$spSiteUrl = "https://$domain.sharepoint.com/sites/$spSiteName"

# Connect to SharePoint Online using the current user's credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $spSiteUrl -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

# Get the current connection context
$spConnection = Get-PnPConnection

# Check if the connection is null
if ($null -eq $spConnection) {
    Write-Output "Not connected."
} else {
    Write-Output "Connected to $($spConnection.Url)."
}

# Get a specific library by its title - most SP sites seem to have 'Documents'
$spLibraryTitle = "Documents"
$spLibrary = Get-PnPList -Identity $spLibraryTitle

# Check if the library exists
if ($null -eq $spLibrary) {
    Write-Output "Library '$spLibraryTitle' not found."
} else {
    Write-Output "Library '$spLibraryTitle' found."
}

# get the relative path to the library
$spLibraryUrl = $spLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Output "'$spLibraryTitle' relative URL is: '$spLibraryUrl'"

# Find a single folder by its name
# To find a named folder, you need the full path of the folder relative to
# the $siteUrl
$spFolderName = $spLibraryUrl+"/path/to/my/folder"
$spFolder = Get-PnPFolder -URL $spFolderName

# Check if the folder exists
if ($null -eq $spFolder) {
    Write-Output "Folder '$spFolderName' not found."
} else {
    Write-Output "Folder '$spFolderName' found."
}

# get the server relative folder URL
$spFolderUrl = $spFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

# Define the target OneDrive folder URL based on current user's name
# Given the '-my' suffix on the domain, a second connection is needed.....
$username = [Environment]::USERNAME
$username = $username -replace '\.', '_'
$odSiteUrl = "https://$domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/"+$username+"_my-company_com"

# Connect to SharePoint Online using the current user's credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $odSiteUrl -UseWebLogin -WarningAction Ignore

# Get the current connection context
$odConnection = Get-PnPConnection

# Check if the connection is null
if ($null -eq $odConnection) {
    Write-Output "Not connected."
} else {
    Write-Output "Connected to $($odConnection.Url)."
}

# Get a specific library by its title
# # In OneDrive, there is typically only one document library called 
# # "Documents". This is where all your files and folders are stored.
$odLibraryTitle = "My Files"
$odLibrary = Get-PnPList -Identity $odLibraryTitle

# Check if the library exists
if ($null -eq $odLibrary) {
    Write-Output "Library '$odLibraryTitle' not found."
} else {
    Write-Output "Library '$odLibraryTitle' found."
}

# get the relative path to the library
$odLibraryUrl = $odLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Output "'$odLibraryTitle' relative URL is: '$odLibraryUrl'"

# Try to put the link in the root folder
$odFolderUrl = $odLibraryUrl

#Get-Help Add-PnPFile -Detailed

# Create a OneDrive shortcut to the SharePoint folder
$odShortcutName = "Shortcut to $spFolder.Name"
Add-PnPFile -Folder $odFolderUrl -SourceUrl $spFolderUrl -Values @{LinkingUrl=$spFolderUrl; LinkingDisplayName=$odShortcutName} -ShortcutUrl

# disconnect
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: @mklement0 - the final `Add-PnPFile`, throws the error; `Add-PnPFile : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`  I've searched for an example but can't find anything that describes a  `-ShortcutURL` parameter.

Comment: From what I can tell, [`Add-PnpFile`](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/documentation/Add-PnPFile.md) has no `-ShortcutUrl` parameter. Are you using a different implementation? See also: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/264533

Comment: @mklement0 - `Get-Help Add-PnPFile` shows two modules with this command; `PnP.Powershell` and `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`.  I've looked at both and can't find a workable parameter set for what I'm trying to do.  `ShortcutURL` was suggested by GH CoPilot.  Tweaking the prompt always gets back around to this.  As I said, I'm really novice in this area....

Comment: I suggest editing your question to clarify which module you're using, ideally with a link to the documentation. (Personally, I'm not familiar with either module.)

Comment: @mklement0 - I tried the answer you linked above. It does create a plain, old, normal internet link. Tweaking it will not create a OneDrive link to Sharepoint.  But thanks for the pointer to the sharepoint community - I'll go post there.